# How do you count the number of words in a column while ignoring blank lines

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following list in a text file:

banana

egg

balloon

green
giant

How do I create a dictionary that counts the words, ignoring the blank lines

my code so far:

```
def make_dictionary(filename):
    text = open(filename,'r').read()
    wordfreq = {}
    for word in text.strip().split('\n'):
        wordfreq[word] = wordfreq.get(word, 0) +1
return wordfreq
```

This will return the counts I need, except it gives me a count for the blank lines as '':7, which I don't need. I cant just split with () because of the double word green giant. Hence I have to split with '\n'

Comment: After the end of the `for` loop before the `return` statement you could insert `del wordfreq[''] # clean up blanks`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the current word, but before assigning it in the dict, check if it is empty, and if so, skip it.

```
for word in text.strip().split('\n'):
    # skip this word if it is blank
    if not word:
        continue
    wordfreq[word] = wordfreq.get(word, 0) +1
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code is relying on the fact that Python considers an empty string, or '' to be a False, while a non-empty string is True

```
def make_dictionary(filename):
    text = open(filename,'r').read()
    wordfreq = {}
    for word in text.strip().split('\n'):
        for line in text:
            if not line.strip():
                continue
            else:
                wordfreq[word] = wordfreq.get(word, 0) +1
return wordfreq
```